# How to use handlebars to display either one or an other value

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I need help understanding the very basics of handlebars.

For example I have the following html code:

```
<div id="box">

</div>
```

and I want it to display either `"Login"` or `"Register"` (strings) inside the div. How do I do it using handlebars? I read many tutorials, but still haven't understood.

Comment: Are you trying to use a [conditional](http://handlebarsjs.com/#conditionals) or are you trying to display a variable's value (in this case containing `Login` or `Register`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional statements like this:

```
{{#if someCondition}}
    <a>Login</a>
{{else}}
    <a>Register</a>
{{/if}}
```

Or it might be easier if you decided in your view code which string to display and passed that into the template, and just output it like this:

```
<div id="box">
    <a>{{loginOrRegister}}</a>
</div>
```

You can do that via the object that your template function takes as an argument, e.g.

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
        loginOrRegister: this.outputLoginOrRegisterText()
    }));
    return this;
}
```

Obviously `this.outputLoginOrRegisterText()` should be defined by you :)

Comment: Please explain the thing below. That's what I want to do, but how exactly do I do this? What do I put into the .js file?

Comment: Have edited my answer to give an example. Hopefully you should be able to adapt it to your needs.